# No such file or directory error on scp command

Tags: unix, scp, codeship

Im using codeship for deployment and it provides a way to access the build machine with ssh:

```
ssh rof@1.2.3.4 -p 65503
```

This works fine and I get into the machine. Now I want to copy a file from the remote machine to my local machine. Im trying:

```
sudo scp -p 65503 -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa rof@1.2.3.4:~/home/rof/cache/app.js /
```

And I get a whole host of errors:

```
cp: 65503: No such file or directory
cp: -v: No such file or directory
cp: -i: No such file or directory
rof@23.20.112.101: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I dont know why it's saying `No such file or directory` for each argument.

`id_rsa` exists and is in `~/.ssh/` directory.

The Permission Denied error appears to be a separate issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to connect via ssh? Just connect via ssh and go to the desired directory. Are you able to list files there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scp with port number specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341032/scp-with-port-number-specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see from looking at the documentation:

[`man scp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

```
 -P port
         Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that
         this option is written with a capital ‘P’, because -p is
         already reserved for preserving the times and modes of the
         file.

 -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the
         original file.
```

So `scp -p` is taken to mean "copy while preserving timestamps" and `65503` is the name of (one of the) source file(s).

Try `scp -P 65503` instead.